# How do I retrieve text from a file stored in a binary table?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-installer

I want to retrieve a script that is stored in the binary table in an MSI.
How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
string query = $"SELECT `Data` FROM `Binary` WHERE `Name`='{sourceName_}'";

using (View view = db_.OpenView(query))
{
    view.Execute();
    Record record = view.Fetch();
    Stream data = record.GetStream(1);    // "data" should contain the script.
    // I don't know what to do with "data" or
    // if it's the right way to do it.
}
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, as to why I removed my answer. When you say you want to retrieve the script do you want to write it to a file? If so then you could use `using (Record record = view.Fetch()){record.GetStream(1, filePath);}`.

Comment: I just need to get hold of the script, if it's stored in a file or variable doesn't really matter. Everything I've tried so far just results in garbage.